# Dell Latitude 7480 laptop has issues with charging

Tags: performance, battery

My Dell Latitude 7480 laptop has strange symptoms related to charging:

- Sometimes it wont charge even though the charger's light is on (not the laptop one), but the battery percentage does not go lower.
- When on charge the laptop is slower.

I think its because it my be too old. I have no knowledge about computer hardware.

Comment: I  think its because it may be too old. I have no knowledge about computer hardware.   ...........   Take it to a local shop and have the hardware assessed

Comment: The battery is most likely dead. Bring it to a computer shop to have the battery replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the battery is old and is becoming nonfunctional. I found that one of these is your replacement.

- https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/pfydresults/6138435

If you are able to follow a tutorial on how to replace the battery such as the link below, I would recommend this to save time and money.

- https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Dell+Latitude+7480++Battery+Replacement/117763

However if you want to be absolutely sure nothing gets damaged, you should take it to a repair shop.